# Python on Mac, setting up the path for an installed module so Python can use

Tags: python, macos, module, path, environment-variables

I finally got a module, dislin, installed (I think) into my site packages directory. This is the install directory:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dislin
```

Despite the seemingly explicit instructions available, I cannot figure out how to allow Python to see this module. My problem is I don't understand paths or environments well in UNIX (I guess). I added this directory to the .bash_profile file, in several places, and I also tried using: `export PYTHONPATH=$DISLIN/python` (and several variations, which included the full path for example) in the terminal. No luck. Python returns "No module named deslin" when I try to import it.

Can anyone give my explicit directions, or a clear explanation as to how to set this up.

BTW here is the contents the dislin dir in site-packages (and a [link to the README](ftp://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/grafik/dislin/darwin/README.DARWIN) within):

```
DISLIN          fonts           libdiscpp.10.dylib  libdislin_d.dylib
README          g95         libdiscpp.dylib     license.txt
bin         gcldir          libdisjava.dylib    man
device.dat      gf          libdislin.10.dylib  map
discpp.h        hlp         libdislin.9.dylib   perl
dislin.h        ifc         libdislin.dylib     python
dislin.log      java            libdislin_d.10.dylib    real64
examples        lib         libdislin_d.9.dylib
```

Comment: This is what my .bash_profile looks like now BTW: # Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deslin

Comment: That should already be on your path – if you are using the correct python. Have you installed something like MacPorts or Fink? Those will many times end up installing their own python which will override and hide the Apple supplied one. One way to tell is what is the output of this: python -c "import sys;print (sys.path);"

Comment: You could also try `which python`

Comment: @DavidK.Hess Thanks. Pretty sure I am using the python indicated as I am installing many other modules to the same dir, and they work fine.

Comment: @AlexL Which came up with: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step by Step instructions on how I got dislin to work on my Mac OS X with Lion**

- Download dislin
- Uncompress dislin

  ```
  tar xvzf dislin-10.2.darwin.intel.64.tar.gz
  ```

This creates a new folder "dislin-10.2"... we are going to call this the DISLIN DOWNLOAD DIRECTORY

- Create a permanent directory home where dislin will live once we install it

  ```
  mkdir /Users/<your username>/dislin
  ```
- Set your environment variables (if no .bash_profile exists, then create one)

  ```
  vim /Users/<your username>/.bash_profile
  ```
- Paste this in there

  ```
  export DISLIN=/Users/<your username>/dislin
  PATH=${PATH}:${DISLIN}/bin

  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DISLIN:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
  export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
  ```
- Source your profile

  ```
  source ~/.bash_profile
  ```
- Run the installer (from inside the DISLIN DOWNLOAD DIRECTORY)

  ```
  ./INSTALL
  ```
- Run python (or ipython) to see if you can import dislin

At this point I got a motif error in python while trying to load dislin, so I had to download and install the dmg (http://www.ist-inc.com/downloads/motif_download.html). Apparently this only happens for Lion+

After the motif install I loaded up ipython again and was able to import dislin with no troubles.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help here. i am sure I am closer to understanding now. Still does not work though after following the instructions (Python will not import dislin). I may have left some typo some where though ;).

Comment: Here is my new .bash_profile BTW: # Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg"

export DISLIN=/Users/wolf/dislin
PATH=${PATH}:${DISLIN}/bin

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DISLIN:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1):

Is your "deslin" with an "e" in the file path listed above just a typo? (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deslin).

I think the package is called dislin with an "i", which means that in python you might be able to:

```
import deslin
```

but you won't be able to:

```
import dislin
```

unless you change the name of that directory from deslin to dislin. You can do that like this on your mac:

```
sudo mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deslin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dislin
```

Comment: thanks. Obviously a big part of the problem. Not working yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Looking more closely at the directory listing, it looks like you extracted the download straight into site-packages? If so, this is the cause of your problems.

Delete site-packages/dislin. Extract the dislin package into a temporary spot (like your Desktop), go into the directory and run the install command. This should correctly create the directory in site-packages for you.